# Cassandra NoHostsAvailableException

Tags: cassandra

I am getting the following issue:

> 2015-05-06 00:00:24,368 648892 INFO [STDOUT] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8109-1:)
>   00:00:24,365 ERROR [DispatcherServlet]
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (tried:
>   /:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout during
>   read), /:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout during
>   read)) com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException:
>   All host(s) tried for query failed (tried:
>   /:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout during
>   read), /:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout during
>   read)) at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:65)
>   at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:256)

The Cluster configuration is 2 Nodes with RF = 1. Running a query from an application which uses secondary index. The query is running fine on the TEST cluster but it is giving the above exception on STAGE cluster. 
I was able to reproduce the issue from my local environment and added  `.withSocketOptions(socket.setReadTimeoutMillis(80000))` in the code which resolved the issue. But if the number of rows increase, I have to increase the above value. There is no error present in the Cassandra system logs and the application is able to connect to the cluster but it is timing out only for the STAGE cluster. Any idea why this might be happening? Configurations for both clusters is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the change detailed in [JAVA-425](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-425) where a query that hits a read timeout marks a host in an unavailable state.   This behavior has been reverted in 2.0.10 which was released Monday and will be included in 2.1.6 when it is released in the coming weeks.  The new behavior is if a query hits the configured read timeout, the host will remain available instead of being in an unavailable state until the driver can reconnect.

Could you try again at java-driver 2.0.10 and let me know if the problem persists?  If you are on driver version 2.1.X you may need to continue using an increasingly higher timeout until 2.1.6 is released.

As far as the issue only existing on your STAGE cluster, the performance of your query is going to be very dependent and your dataset and environment, especially with secondary indexes (which in general are only recommended for specific use cases).  I'd take a look at [When to use an index](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html?scroll=concept_ds_sgh_yzz_zj__when-no-index) to determine if Secondary Indexes are right for your use case.

Comment: Hi @Andy. I am using 2.0.10 but even after increasing the timeout to 200000ms, I am getting the same error. I am seeing the error only in the Stage cluster. The query runs fine on the test and production cluster. All servers are of the same configuration.

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your data, query and/or cassandra cluster.  It would be worth enabling tracing to see what could be taking so long (http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/tracing_t.html & https://academy.datastax.com/demos/datastax-java-driver-request-tracing, or use DevCenter which has built in tracing) .  If you have queries taking more than 200 seconds, there could be something wrong with your cluster.